# Simple python script that sets my dev environment

Tags: python

I'm learning python and have built a simple script that just sets up my dev environment when working on front-end projects. I'm not very used to python and imagine there are probably numerous improvements to my code:

```
import subprocess
import pyautogui
import webbrowser
from time import sleep

WAIT_BETWEEN_COMMANDS: int = 5

# what is the type for this?
# with 'dict[str, str]', it returns "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable"
COMMANDS: object[str, str] = {
    "LOCATE_PROJECT": "cd ~/Documents/Coding/Projects/Practice/project-template-gql",
    "LOCATE_CLIENT": "cd client",
    "LOCATE_SERVER": "cd server",
    "RUN_CLIENT": "npm start",
    "RUN_SERVER": "npm run dev",
}


def open_cli_tab() -> None:
    pyautogui.keyDown("ctrl")
    pyautogui.keyDown("shift")
    pyautogui.press("~")
    pyautogui.keyUp("ctrl")
    pyautogui.keyUp("shift")


def run_commands(commands) -> None:
    for command in commands:
        pyautogui.typewrite(command)
        pyautogui.press("enter")


def switch_to_vsc() -> None:
    print("switching")
    pyautogui.keyDown("command")
    pyautogui.press("space")
    pyautogui.keyUp("command")
    pyautogui.typewrite("visual studio code")
    pyautogui.press("enter")


def run_frontend() -> None:
    switch_to_vsc()
    open_cli_tab()
    sleep(WAIT_BETWEEN_COMMANDS)
    commands: list[str] = [
        COMMANDS["LOCATE_PROJECT"],
        COMMANDS["LOCATE_CLIENT"],
        COMMANDS["RUN_CLIENT"],
    ]
    run_commands(commands)


def run_server() -> None:
    open_cli_tab()
    sleep(WAIT_BETWEEN_COMMANDS)
    commands: list[str] = [
        COMMANDS["LOCATE_PROJECT"],
        COMMANDS["LOCATE_SERVER"],
        COMMANDS["RUN_SERVER"],
    ]
    run_commands(commands)


def open_extra_tab() -> None:
    open_cli_tab()
    sleep(WAIT_BETWEEN_COMMANDS)
    commands: list[str] = [
        COMMANDS["LOCATE_PROJECT"]
    ]
    run_commands(commands)


def open_browser_tabs() -> None:
    chrome_path: str = "open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s"
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open("https://github.com/")
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open("http://localhost:8000/graphql")
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open("http://localhost:3000/")


def open_apps() -> None:
    chrome: str = "Google Chrome"
    mongo: str = "MongoDB Compass"
    vsc: str = "Visual Studio Code"

    apps: list[str] = [chrome, vsc, mongo]

    for app in apps:
        subprocess.run(["open", "-a", app])
        print("Opening " + app)


open_apps()
sleep(30)
run_frontend()
run_server()
open_extra_tab()
open_browser_tabs()
```

I also have a few questions:

1. When adding types in python, does it only warn of any errors when trying to run the program? I'm used to writing typescript with react which warns you of errors immediately, but my IDE with python seems to let me declare wrong types - e.g. `SOME_STRING: number = 'test'`
2. Is it normal to define a load of functions at the top, or is it better to import them from another file to minimise the code in one file?
3. When running `python3 filename.py` from VSC’s terminal window, everything works correctly (pressing the keys, writing ‘visual studio code’, printing ‘start’, ‘end’, etc), but when running it from a separate terminal, pyautogui commands seem to not run. Any idea why?

Any feedback would be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: For your subscriptable error to be fixed you need newer Python

Comment: If you're stuck on old Python, use Dict instead of dict for typing

Comment: Useful comments, thank you. I already have python 3.8 so maybe I will upgrade to 3.11, but it was resolved by using Dict as you correctly said

Comment: are there any other improvements you can think of? Is adding `-> None` right? should I put the functions in another file to minimise the code? Are there any other things that might be better? Also is adding this correct: `def run_commands(commands: List[str]) -> None:`

Comment: In addition to comments above, I'd suggest removing almost all annotations from this code. `something: str = 'foo'` is absolutely redundant: all type checkers will deduce `something` type as `str` anyway.  `WAIT_BETWEEN_COMMANDS` should be annotated as `typing.Final` (usual thing for constants). Finally - no, type annotations are not enforced by runtime at all, and this is the most important thing about typing in python.

Comment: You don't need annotations to run the program, and they may be invalid and it will have no runtime effect (well, introspection will cry, but it's rarely a problem). Types are checked/verified by third-party tools, like IDE - e.g. pycharm and vscode have such plugins/tools (fans of them, please correct me - are they built in or shipped separately?) - or `mypy` - it is a separate type checker maintained by python core team. There are also `pytype` and `pyre` for similar goals. Python itself does not validate your annotations.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but why should `WAIT_BETWEEN_COMMANDS` be renamed to `typing.Final`?